# How to set the last element of an array as a certain number?

Tags: c

Say I have an array that sets values for 5 elements. How do I make the last one to print out as 100?

```
int n[5];
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("Please enter value %d: \n",i+1);
        scanf(" %d", &n[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Set your loop condition to `i < 4` and manually set `n[4] = 100;` outside of your loop

Comment: @GovindParmar under int n[5] I'd write n[4]=100;

Comment: @GovindParmar Anyway you can write that as an answer so I can give your props?

Comment: @danglingpointer Wouldn't that be out of bounds?

Comment: @danglingpointer looks like a good way to get yourself shot in the foot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your loop to not scan for the final element in your array, and fill that out with the hard-coded value of 100 in your code:

```
int n[5];
n[4] = 100;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    printf("Please enter value %d: \n",i+1);
    scanf(" %d", &n[i]);
}
```

Note that since your `for` loop no longer asks for a value for `n[4]` from the user, it doesn't matter whether the line `n[4] = 100;` comes before or after your loop.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would solve this problem like this:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 5

void myFunc()
{
  int n[ARRAY_SIZE];
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE-1; i++)
  {
    printf("Please enter value %d: \n",i+1);
    scanf(" %d", &n[i]);
  }
  // now, i == ARRAY_SIZE-1
  n[i] = 100;
}
```

This will work for any size array.